# Old metadata notation is not supported anymore in Artifactory CURL request

Tags: artifactory

I am trying to push my zip files into Artifactory using CURL requests, but I get a status 409 error saying old metadata notation not supported anymore.

Can anyone point to correct documentation or way to do this?

```
root@84ddb6dc0dff: 
curl -uadmin:AP6uUoG1o25Butgo7VfzRubufPB -T /myfilepath/MyZip.zip "http://My-Artifactory-Server/artifactory/MyGenericRepo/MyZip.zip"
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 409,
    "message" : "Old metadata notation is not supported anymore: MyZip.zip"
  } ]
```

Comment: I think I figured out that, 

My file path had ":"  colon in it.
so I think ":" is not supported by Artifactory in path's


Can someone quickly confirm?

Thanks.

Comment: Confirmed. You can't have ':' as part of your path.